# `dotnet run` vs `dotnet publish`

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have an asp.net core project that runs fine in VS and even with `dotnet run` but when I `dotnet publish -c Release -o publish` it and try to run it with `dotnet publish/Web.dll` it runs for a bit then fails with

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EncoderServiceCollectionExtensions.AddWebEncoders(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
      :
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Web.Program.main(String[] args) in C:\_work\website_tq\tqit8\Web\Startup.fs:line 93
```

The netstandard.dll is placed in `publish/refs`.  Is that a problem?

Comment: Do you have some appseetings.json file or extra assemblies? You can set for these types of files flags in .csproj file that you want them copy to your output folder. There are options like 'Always' 'PreserveNewest' etc...  Probably you are missing just some files.. you can try to copy them in the publish folder first  to see if its really the problem.

Comment: @Vojtech There is an appsettings.json file & it is copied to publish.

Comment: Hmm, then maybe, do you have some '<HintPath>' attributtes which are absoulute r relative in .csproj file? Check that, these two things are the first one to come to my mind. Otherwise I do not know. I remembere I had simmilar problem when I was using library written in .NET Core 3.0 from app that was using .NET Core 2.1 and it just could not load the library.. I had same error. But I couldnt run it at all (even on 'dotnet run')

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?